# Pivot and concat values Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    contactId    ticker
0    ABC         XYZ
1    ABC         ZZZ
0    BCA         YYY
```

Creating a pivot like so:

```
final_df = final_df.pivot_table(index='contactId', columns='ticker', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

Results in the following output:

```
ticker       XYZ    ZZZ    YYY
contactId    
ABC          1      1      0
BCA          0      0      1
```

As an intermediary step (see request below), I am assuming we need to transform the pivot so that if value >0 then ticker, else (blank). ie:

```
ticker       XYZ    ZZZ    YYY
contactId    
ABC          XYZ    ZZZ      
BCA                        YYY
```

Because the output I am looking for is list of space separated tickers + a text string per contactId:

```
contactId   ticker    description
ABC         XYZ ZZZ   The client is holding: XYZ ZZZ
BCA         YYY       The client is holding: YYY
```

For the intermediary step I tried the following (but it through a ValueError: Grouper for 'ticker' not 1-dimensional):

```
final_df = final_df.pivot_table(index='contactId', columns='ticker', values='ticker', fill_value="")
```

Can you please assist? Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: We can use groupby instead: `df1=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('contactId')['ticker'].sum().reset_index())` 
`df1['Description']= "the client is holding:"+df1['ticker']`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this didnt work quite right. the ticker field concatenated all the individual tickers into a string, but there is no (space) separation between each one which is critical

Comment: Try this route: `df1=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('contactId')['ticker'].transform(lambda x: ' '.join(x)))`
`df1['Description']= "the client is holding: "+df1['ticker']`
`df1.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Sorry no go: "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 66119 elements, new values have 73862 elements"

Comment: I'm not sure what dataframe is yielding that error; but for the one you provided above, it works. Provide more test data then.

Comment: There were other columns, but they should have been unique. I changed dataframe to only have contactId and ticker columns, but same issue. I ran df.drop_duplicates() too before executing. I think it has to do with indexing. Dataframe is sorted by contact id, and every time it is a new contactId, the index goes back to 0 (as per the updated dataframe). I did add as_index=False but still getting same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @sharatpc 's suggestion, after adding the below to remove duplicates:

```
df = df[pd.notnull(df['contactId'])]
```

This worked for me:

```
df = df.set_index('contactId').groupby('contactId')['ticker'].transform(lambda x: ' '.join(x)).reset_index()
```